# how can I make jackson in a swagger context throw an exception instead of accepting an integer for a boolean field?

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, swagger

I have a multi-module maven Springboot project in Java.

Resource classes are generated from yaml, so that, e.g.

```
type: object
required:
  - myFlag
properties:
  myFlag:
    type: boolean
    example: false
```

yields a resource class with a Boolean property

```
  @JsonProperty("myFlag")
  private Boolean myFlag;
```

My problem begins when I test ways someone could post this resource with wrong values (I expect success only when this field is posted with JSON yielding a boolean, e.g.

```
{
  "main": "whatever",
  "subpart": {
    "myFlag": false
  }
}
```

).

However, jackson evidently tolerates numbers instead of booleans. I'd like it not to. I have looked for tuning settings that might have a bearing on this, but didn't find any obvious ones (for example

```
spring.jackson.deserialization.accept-float-as-int=false
```

solved a related problem of parsing that was too lenient for our taste.) I tried setting several but haven't been able to get a HttpMessageNotReadableException exception -- the usual variety for these kinds of events -- to fire.

Incidentally, these exceptions fire as hoped for in unit tests such as:

```
   @Test
    public void post_with_Integer_instead_of_Boolean_yields_400_Status() throws Exception {
        ResultActions resultActions = mockMvc
            .perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders
                .post(PATH)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
                .content("{\"main\": \"whatever\", \"subpart\": {\"myFlag\": 123}}"));
        resultActions.andExpect(status().is(400));
    }
```

but, alas, not when the service is "really" running. This would seem to be a clue, but I haven't been able to figure out how to use it.

I'd be grateful for any pointers that would help me get a handle on this.